Почему Java Spring Boot не предоставляет доступ к статическим данным сразу?
Всем привет. помогите разобраться. у меня бэкэнд серверная часть на Java Spring Boot, а фронт на React (вдруг это важно).
Так вот, я с фронта загружаю файлы в папку

\src\main\resources\static\uploads\categories

и при переходе на страницу файла

http://localhost:8080/uploads/categories/photo1712842742.jpeg

выходит ошибка

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Sun Jun 09 21:50:38 VLAT 2024 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
Found, status=404).

я гуглил, и нашёл, что можно настроить доступ к файлам через application либо файл конфигурации, если нужен доступ ко всей структуре файлов \resources\static\uploads**
я создал такой файл в таком виде
package main.configurations;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/uploads/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/uploads/")
                .setCachePeriod(0); // Отключение кеширования
    }
}

не помогло. и в таком виде:
package main.configurations;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/uploads/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:uploads/")
                .setCachePeriod(0); // Отключение кеширования
    }
}


но тоже не помогло. пожалуйста, подскажите как сделать так, чтоб они были сразу доступны, а не только после перезагрузки сервера.

пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

извините, исправил

Tomcat не может найти файлы, поэтому выдает ошибку 404. Либо неверный url либо файлов там нет. Попробуйте загрузить файлы вручную с помощью getResource или что-то подобное.

addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/uploads/")

В этом случае будут доступны файлы из \src\main\resources\static\uploads скопированные в classpath при сборке, что очевидно, не подходит т.к. должны отдаваться файлы, загруженные на сервер во время работы приложения.
.addResourceHandler("/static/uploads/**")
.addResourceLocations("file:uploads/")

Выглядит, как будто бы static здесь лишний, а вот в части с file нужно понимать, что это относительный путь относительно корня проекта, можно указать абсолютный, а лучше вынести в конфигурацию приложения.
Также, spring boot должен из коробки поддерживать указание путей со статическими файлами в пропертях:
spring.web.resources.static-locations=file:/my/uploads,classpath:/static/

правильно я понимаю, что лучше убрать java class и настройки указать в application.yml
upload:
  dir: uploads/
spring:
  web:
    resources:
      static-locations: classpath:/static/, file:uploads/
  resources:
    cache:
      period: 0s

сама папка uploads где должна находится? \src\main\resources\uploads или в корне проекта, на уровне src?

Спасибо.
В общем registry.addResourceHandler("/uploads/**") сделал таким. Директория куда грузятся файлы стала в корне проекта
